# Internet on Android apps fail when on ethernet cable

Tags: internet, certificates, ethernet

I have a strange problem. When connected to WiFi, I have no issues. When I connect a UTP cable to my device via a USB ethernet adaptor, I can browse the internet, but apps won't work.

I can, for example, browse https://www.youtube.com, but the YouTube app fails to connect to the network.

I tested on 2 medical smartphones (Spectralink and Ascom Myco 3) on 2 different networks. No firewalls or spam filters on the network.
Both have the same issue.

I have a medical app that can not connect to its server on port 443 when on the cable. When using a web browser to connect, it says it doesn't trust the certificate. Again, on WiFi, it's fine.
It seems to me that the cabled network has a different way of handling certificates. Can there be a difference?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: A network does not handle certificates at all, but proxies in between do (often used e.g. by companies for HTTPS traffic inspection). What network and internet connection is the ethernet adapter connected to?

Comment: True. But it somehow is different in this case, which doesn't seem logical to me.To rule out the network, I tried different networks including a consumer connection, directly connected to the modem.

Comment: I would recommend trying a different network with a different internet connection and see if it works or not, thus if it is a network or a device problem.

Comment: Two devices, three networks. Same result on all combinations

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. As Robert has mentioned, it seems the ethernet/modem is intercepting the connection (using MitM), thus the certificate that the device sees is different from the real certificate. Possibly related on our sister site: [Information Security - Is it common practice for companies to MITM HTTPS traffic?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/107542/59741)

Comment: I like the way you’re thinking. MiTM would indeed cause an untrusted connection. 
But that’s not the case. Not on all three networks. Also, I get the correct certificate when using the internet browser. I would have seen the mitm certificate there also. Correct?